# SO: How to avoid giving bounty/chosen correct answer?

Tags: discussion, support

So I made a question a while back, and since no one answered, I set a bounty for it.

I've been getting random answers in the best grammatically constructed sentences, and explanation and they are not even right, but people UP-VOTE them.

I don't care about the points awarded to him, but I want to make sure that is NOT the selected answer. That way someone might be still interested in answering the question.

P.s.
Link to original question - [Similar to Tinder Instagram Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367673/similar-to-tinder-instagram-connect)

Comment: Only *you* decide the "selected" (*accepted?*) answer.

Comment: I agree, nobody answered your question very well. Perhaps you could have included your desired programming language for more specific answers, if that was your intention.